# A SQL Query without Key Lookups takes 5-30 seconds to execute

Tags: azure-sql-database

I've pulled a query from our production environment due to how long it takes 5-30 seconds. Initially, the execution plan revealed several key lookups, which I've managed to eliminate by adding the missing columns to the non-clustered index. However, despite these improvements and no apparent key lookups in the current execution plan, the query execution time still ranges between 5 to 30 seconds, which is beyond our performance expectations.

Here's a brief overview of the query context:

- The query involves multiple joins and filters on a relatively large dataset.
- No key lookups or other apparent red flags are present in the current execution plan.
- It's an Azure SQL database.

Execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HygQlZcnp

What could be causing the performance issues with this query? I can provide additional information if necessary, such as details about the indexes we currently have, or any other required data. Just let me know what you need.

Comment: Where are you getting 5 to 30 seconds from? The plan uploaded executed in 1066 ms?

Comment: @MartinSmith, in Application Insights, https://i.imgur.com/rC5NOMs.png

Comment: @MartinSmith, SQL Sentry Plan explorer has the following warning message: https://i.imgur.com/EKK1WA4.png. Almost every call to this query is 31-32 seconds

Comment: Did you try executing the query manually and checking how long that takes? XML says this : <QueryTimeStats ElapsedTime="1066" CpuTime="1027"></QueryTimeStats>
Perhaps your delays are not in SQL itself, or if you have occasional slow queries it might be blocking or something

Comment: @YannickLiekens, yeah that's accurate. The XML data that you see is from running the same query with the same parameters manually. However, the issue is that only that particular query tends to exceed the 30-second threshold according to the App Insights logs.

Comment: I assume that the query that the app executes is the interior one and not the COUNT(?) that you have provided as a sample?  If that is the case, then I can see why a client could potentially struggle with it.  20K rows, 12MB of data.  I would confirm that the query they are executing does so in the 1 second that it seems like according to the plan and then verify if the app is struggling to paint the data or process it.  Making the query faster won't solve the problem if the client can't consume the data any faster.

Comment: @JonathanFite, I think I see where you're going. Here is the "interior" query: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryOcOO5h6 (which is the same but without the count). The EF Core code is as following: https://pastebin.com/Anmdq4zz

Comment: Think your main task will be finding out where the delays are. Capture the queries executed on your SQL and check if they are actually running that long. If they do run long in SQL, try tracking wait types, could be blocking issue or something

Comment: Looks like it might be worth usin `AsSplitQuery` rather than that huge joined Thing.